# Deploy Azure Cloud Service from Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cloud-services

Can we setup Azure Cloud Service deployment as a part of the build process to have a similar result that Visual Studio wizard gives?

[image: VS Publish Cloud Service Wizard]

**UPD.** We found "Azure Cloud Service Deployment" build step, but it fails with following unexpected error (because storage account is set actually, see the full log below).

[image: Build step]

```
CurrentStorageAccountName is not set. Use Set-AzureSubscription
subname -CurrentStorageAccountName storageaccount to set it.
```

The full log:

```
Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\tasks\AzureCloudPowerShellDeployment\1.0.13\Publish-AzureCloudDeployment.ps1
Looking for Azure PowerShell module at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Azure.psd1
AzurePSCmdletsVersion= 0.9.1
Get-ServiceEndpoint -Name ***cut** -Context Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Worker.Common.TaskContext
Username= ***cut**
Add-AzureAccount -Credential $psCredential
azureSubscriptionId= ***cut**
azureSubscriptionName= ***cut**
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId ***cut**
ConnectedServiceName= ***cut** 
ServiceName= ***cut**
ServiceLocation= East US
StorageAccount= ***cut**
CsPkg= C:\a\c409f63f\***cut**.cspkg
CsCfg= C:\a\c409f63f\***cut**.cscfg
Slot= Production
AllowUpgrade= true
Find-Files -SearchPattern C:\a\c409f63f\***cut**.cscfg
serviceConfigFile= C:\a\c409f63f\***cut**.cscfg
Find-Files -SearchPattern C:\a\c409f63f\***cut**.cspkg
servicePackageFile= C:\a\c409f63f\***cut**.cspkg
Get-AzureService -ServiceName ***cut** -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Applying any configured diagnostics extensions.
New-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtensionConfig -Role ***cut** -StorageContext  -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath C:\a\c409f63f\***cut**.xml
New-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtensionConfig -Role ***cut** -StorageContext  -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath C:\a\c409f63f\***cut**.xml
Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName crgd-scheduler -Slot Production -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-AzureDeployment -Upgrade -ServiceName ***cut** -Package C:\a\c409f63f\***cut**.cspkg -Configuration C:\a\c409f63f\***cut**.cscfg -Slot Production -ExtensionConfiguration 
CurrentStorageAccountName is not set. Use Set-AzureSubscription subname -CurrentStorageAccountName storageaccount to set it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally succeeded with "Azure PowerShell" generic build step and the custom PS script that uses Azure API to create/update Azure deployment (`New-AzureDeployment`, `Set-AzureDeployment`).

[image: vso build step]

The great article that contains the full script is here: http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2014/02/06/deploying-cloud-services-to-azure-with-powershell/.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup and login to the subscription before you try any commands.

I usually make it part of my PowerShell, and if you search around you can find out how to encrypt your credentials to not have them in the script.

Comment: It's linked and selected on the build step definition on the Visual Studio Online UI. Please see the picture in updated post. Any other thought considering this fact?